# Dealing with interrupt and sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

I was thinking that I could calmly Thread.sleep() on an interrupted thread. Sonar doesn't think so, of course.

In some circumstates we should waiting for conditions, even if an interrupt occured. Is there anything wrong, for example, with the code below? Is there any better solution?

```java
private void waitFinish() {
    boolean wasInterrupted = false;
    while (asyncProgressCounter.get() > 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { // NOSONAR
            wasInterrupted = true;
        }
    }
    if (wasInterrupted) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    onFinish();
}
```

Comment: You don't deal with interrupts in Java running in some JVM. Perhaps with [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) and these are [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)-specific. Signals are mostly Unix-like, and thread-unfriendly. Read [*Operating systems: three easy pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: You should think in terms of threads running [event loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) so think in terms of [message passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing)

Comment: You ask if there is a better solution. What do you want to achieve? It looks like you are delaying shutdown of this thread (possibly forever) and trying to do onFinish() before shutting down. Is that your intent? Is your code interrupting this thread? Or are you anticipating that a library or container will interrupt it?

Comment: My intent is waiting for all tasks to finish, than run some shutdown code. (These tasks are callbacks invoked by a third party library.) Technically, users of my API could set the 'interrupted' flag. (But, even if no interrupt could be thrown, I must catch this exception, and Sonar will alert me, if I ignore it.)

Comment: Here is a nice article about the subject: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the Java thread interrupt mechanism is not the low level interrupt mechanism you're thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

The displayed code is correct if you need to keep the state of the interrupt status of the thread. As `Thread.sleep()` [clears the interrupt status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930189/why-does-thread-sleep-clear-the-interrupted-flag), you need the additional `wasInterrupted` flag instead of just calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in the catch block like normally.

In most code you don't see the "full version" like this, because they don't expect to be interrupted and have no logic to try to recover from interruption. Even in the above code an interrupt won't stop the loop from running. The actual usefulness depends on other code and how it behaves depending on that thread's interruption state.

(I'm assuming you have to resort to "busy-sleep" because the async operations have no other way of notifying they're finished (such as a `CountDownLatch`). While the code represents the correct way to handle keeping the interrupt status, it's not a good general purpose approach.)

---

For more information (and confusion) about this see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087475/when-does-javas-thread-sleep-throw-interruptedexception).

Basically it's good form to keep the interrupted state of the thread, but in practice it's not as important as one might think. Additional confusion is caused by *spurious interrupts* meaning that your thread could be interrupted without a real cause, and it should not stop what it's doing. For this it's recommended to keep a flag such as `shutdown`, so when you interrupt a thread you can check the flag to see if it's an interrupt meaning to shut down. However in my 20 years of Java I've yet to understand whether spurious interrupts are a real possiblity or just a theoretical one.